# How to reuse a signature?

Tags: signature, raku

Is it possible to assign a signature to a variable and then reuse it in different functions/methods?
I've found `my $sig = :($a, $b);` but I don't know how I could use the variable as a signature in a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
my $sig = :( $a, $b );

sub foo ( &function where { .signature ~~ $sig } ) {}

sub bar    ( $p, $q ) {}
sub qux    ( $waldo ) {}

foo &bar;

say "OK at line 10"; # OK at line 10

foo &qux;            # Constraint type check failed ... line 12".
```